# Issue with state view and urlrouter

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Below is codepen [URL](http://codepen.io/gauravcoder/pen/JGZjrb):

I have an issue with tabs and URL router.

What I want, when someone clicks **view cart** button at bottom:

1. To show view with title "View Cart" and some dummy content like [this](http://goo.gl/t1ALJe)
2. Also remove  **top tabs ** and show title bars with heading as show in reference [url](http://goo.gl/t1ALJe)

How can it be done?
pls help

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ionicApp">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title>Ionic page</title>
<link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//fabricjs.com/lib/fabric_with_gestures.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeTabCtrl">


<ion-side-menus>
  <ion-side-menu-content>
  <ion-nav-view> </ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="right">
   <div class="list">
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"><i class="icon ion-email"></i> Check mail</a>
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-chatbubble-working"></i>Call Ma</a> 
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-mic-a"></i> Record album</a> 
   <a class="item item-icon-left" href="#"> <i class="icon ion-person-stalker"></i> Friends</a>
   </div>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>  

<ion-footer-bar  class="bar-footer btn-footer bar-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-positive"> View cart Page </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-calm"> View checkout page </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>


<script id="templates/tabs.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-tabs class="tabs-striped tabs-positive tabs-top tabs-top-my tabs-icon-only" animation="fade-in-out">

        <ion-tab title="tab1" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab1">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab1-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab2" icon="ion-home" href="#/tab/tab2">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab2-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>

        <ion-tab title="tab3" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab3">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab3-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab4" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab4">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab4-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab5" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.tab5">
          <ion-nav-view name="tab5-tab"></ion-nav-view>
        </ion-tab>
        <ion-tab title="tab6" icon="ion-android-apps" ng-click="toggleRightSideMenu()"  ui-sref="tabs.tab6">
            <ion-nav-view name="tab6-tab"></ion-nav-view>

        </ion-tab>

      </ion-tabs>
    </script> 
<script id="templates/tab1.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab1">
        <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
                <div class="col col-25 p0">
                  <div class="img-box">
                    <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer">

                    </ion-scroll>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col col-50" id="canvascontainer">
                                        tab 1
                </div>
                <div class="col col-25 p0">
                  <div class="img-box">
                    <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer1">

                    </ion-scroll>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </ion-view>
</script> 

<script id="templates/tab2.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-view view-title="tab2">
      <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
          <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
                <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer">
                </ion-scroll>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50" id="canvascontainer">
                                        tab 2
            </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
                <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="y" class="my-imgs-scroll" id="maincontainer1">
                </ion-scroll>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>

    </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab3.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab3">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50">                    <canvas id="canvas3"></canvas> </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab4.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab4">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
              <div class="img-box">
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab5.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab5">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
            <div class="row p0">
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
            <div class="img-box">
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
            <div class="col col-25 p0">
            <div class="img-box">
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/tab6.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="tab6">
       <div class="my-content-tabs scroll-content ionic-scroll  has-header has-footer has-tabs-mytop">
        <div class="row p0">
        <div class="col col-25 p0">
        <div class="img-box">
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-50"> Coming Soon   </div>
        <div class="col col-25 p0">
        <div class="img-box">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </ion-view>
</script> 
<script id="templates/nav-stack.html" type="text/ng-template">
      <ion-view view-title="Tab Nav Stack">
        <ion-content class="padding">
          <p><img src="http://ionicframework.com/img/diagrams/tabs-nav-stack.png" style="width:100%"></p>
        </ion-content>
      </ion-view>
    </script> 
<script>
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic', 'ionicApp.controllers']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('tabs', {
      url: "/tab",
      abstract: true,
      templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
    })
    .state('tabs.tab1', {
      url: "/tab1",
      views: {
        'tab1-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab1.html",
          controller: 'Tab1Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab2', {
      url: "/tab2",
      views: {
        'tab2-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab2.html",
  controller: 'Tab2Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab3', {
      url: "/tab3",
      views: {
        'tab3-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab3.html",
          controller:'Tab3Ctrl'
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab4', {
      url: "/tab4",
      views: {
        'tab4-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab4.html"
        }
      }
    })
    .state('tabs.tab5', {
      url: "/tab5",
      views: {
        'tab5-tab': {
          templateUrl: "templates/tab5.html"
        }
      }
    })
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/tab1");

})
.controller('HomeTabCtrl', function($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
  $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();
  };
  $scope.toggleRightSideMenu = function() {
      console.log('rigth open')
    $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleRight();
  };
  console.log('HomeTabCtrl');
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear: do you want the tab navigation bar on top? Or do you wish to show only a tab bar on bottom?

Comment: Would help if there was an explanation in demo. No idea what we are supposed to see there on which view

Comment: @charlietfl pls see http://goo.gl/t1ALJe i want like this when view cart is clicked

Comment: When we do what in demo? Demo has no explanation in it

Comment: @charlietfl i updated question hope it is fine now

Comment: @saurav: Maybe you could use a nested tabs approach...

Comment: bro can u edit my codepen

Answer (score 3):

I can answer your Requirement using the `$ionicModal`

**HTML**

```
  <script id="add-or-edit-cart.html" type="text/ng-template">

        <ion-modal-view>
            <ion-header-bar>
                <h1 class="title">{{ action }} Page</h1>
                <div class="buttons">
                    <button ng-click="deleteCart()" class="button button-icon icon ion-close"></button>
                </div>
            </ion-header-bar>
            <ion-content>
                <div class="list list-inset">
                    <label class="item item-input">
                      Dummy Text
                    </label>
                   
                </div>
               
            </ion-content>
        </ion-modal-view>

    </script>
```

Add `ng-click` to the View cart present in the footer

```
<ion-footer-bar  class="bar-footer btn-footer bar-light">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button ng-click="vm.showCart()" ng-controller="OverviewController as vm" class="button  button-block button-positive"> View cart Page </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="button  button-block button-calm"> View checkout page </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</ion-footer-bar>
```

**JS**

Add the Following Controller

```
.controller('OverviewController', function ($scope, $ionicModal) {
    var vm = this;
   
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('add-or-edit-cart.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    vm.showCart = function () {
        $scope.Cart = {};
        $scope.action = 'Cart';
        $scope.isAdd = true;
        $scope.modal.show();
    };

    


    $scope.deleteCart = function () {
        
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });

    return vm;
```

so that top Tabs witll be removed and some text is seen. here is working [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKBaEd?editors=0010)

#### Update

As you requested you dont need using $ionicModal , you can go with the  **transitionTo**

Modify your Existing Controller to like this

**HTML**

```
 <script id="templates/add-or-edit-cart.html" type="text/ng-template">

         <ion-view view-title="View Cart" nav-bar-class="bar-balanced">
            <ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive" align-title="center">
                <ion-nav-back-button>
                </ion-nav-back-button>
            </ion-nav-bar>
            <ion-content class="padding">
                        
                    <a class="button icon ion-chevron-left" href="#/tab/facts"> Back</a>
              Dummy Text 
                
            </ion-content>
        </ion-view>
         

    </script>
```

**JS**

Modify **state** like this

```
.state('carty', {
      url: "/carty",
       templateUrl: "templates/add-or-edit-cart.html",
        controller:'OverviewController'
  
    })
```

Controller Code

```
.controller('OverviewController', function ($scope, $ionicModal,$state) {
    var vm = this;
   
    $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('add-or-edit-cart.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function (modal) {
        $scope.modal = modal;
    });

    vm.showCart = function () {
     
        $state.transitionTo('carty');
    };

    


    $scope.deleteCart = function () {
        //birthdayService.deleteBirthday($scope.birthday);
        $scope.modal.hide();
    };

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
        $scope.modal.remove();
    });

    return vm;

})
;
```

last thing here is your working [codepen](http://codepen.io/webruster/pen/RrqWyW?editors=1000)

Comment: i want to use state not modal

Answer (score -1):

add state of dummy page in your route config and give that state as ui-sref in view cart button.

Comment: @saurav have u tried this way..!i guess this is the simple way..to do..!

Answer (score -1):

Check this pen: http://codepen.io/toddhalfpenny/pen/bNyLYB

Take a look at

```
<ion-view cache-view="false" id="store-visit-wrapper" hide-tabs>
```